# PHPUnit Symfony 2 Submit Form

Tags: php, forms, symfony, phpunit

I'm trying to send a form with PHPUnit. I followed the official documentation but I don't know what I'm doing wrong...

```
$client = static::createClient();
$crawler = $client->request('GET', '/demo/create/');
$form = $crawler->selectButton('Create Button')->form();
```

I have a submit button with Create Button text, but when I try the PHPUnit test I get the following error:

```
InvalidArgumentException: The current node list is empty.
```

I also tried filtering with form ID, but same error... What I'm doing wrong? I've created the form with the Form from Symfony 2.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the button is not found. Debug your page like this:

```
$client = static::createClient();
$crawler = $client->request('GET', '/demo/create/');
$button = $crawler->selectButton('Create Button');
var_dump($button);
```

so you can see if the button is actually found. Check for missing spaces / wrong capitalization in the button text.